# When installing Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP 15-da0135NQ I don't get the screen to manually confgure my partitions

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, software-installation, updates

I have tried to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP machine and failed miserably.

I downloaded the Ubuntu image, created a bootable USB with rufus, turned off my laptop, turned it back on, pressed ESC and selected boot options (F9). I had 2 options both with UEFI after them. Picked the USB and it takes me to a screen with only one option -> Install UBUNTU.

I installed ubuntu that way. After going through the basic configuration (timezone, language etc) I get prompted with a message about forcing UEFI or "go back". Not sure what this is. I selected Continue with UEFI and it just started installing the UBUNTU. It works... only I cannot connect to the internet and I think there are 2 more profiles in it that I haven't created (must have been something that was already installed on my laptop from where I bought the laptop - INTEL IPOS - basically a presentation screen of the laptop's system configuration that I have seen many times running on the laptops on display in shops).

What is this? Is there a problem with the bios configuration? I have no idea how to go forward from here. At the moment I have a copy of ubuntu running on my latop, with no ability to connect to wireless connections and two random profiles that I haven't created.

Comment: There are many Ubuntu images/ISOs you can download, and many sites that offer it.  I'd always suggest only the main download site, or an official mirror (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors).  Did you verify your download? or verify the install-media prior to install?  Your initial description reads like you downloaded from an unofficial site, didn't verify download or media prior to install - problems possibly resulting from this skipped steps.  (https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu or pressing a key when you see kbd-in-rectangle & person-in-circle to get menu..)

Comment: If you did this verify steps & install is good, but have wireless connection issues, what documentation have you tried to follow, what steps did you try and what were the results, eg. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide ..

Comment: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?country=GB&version=18.04.2&architecture=amd64. this is the link I sent to the person to use for download. I haven't checked anything before. I haven't tried to troubleshoot the wireless because I don't have internet connection (or an ethernet cable) - I am doing this fresh reinstall through messenger video chat.

Comment: The troubleshooting documentation requires only the machine with Ubuntu installed (that you are trying to troubleshoot).  Yes it assumes you're reading it on something, so another machine/tablet/phone so as to read the commands you enter, and thumb-drive to copy the results to for posting on this site, or Ubuntu forums etc if you can't resolve it yourself.   Your link is good, but it still didn't say if you checked the download, nor the install media (steps done after the download from your link)